# Issues with > and < in C#

Tags: c#

I have an issue with a small piece of code I've made.
For the code I have to make a small check. When the value of `_mmdTextBox` is bigger then 1999 it should give a `MessageBx.Show("Value to high")`.
If the value is smaller then 0 there should be a `MessageBox.Show("Value to low")`.

This is what I have made so far:

```
private void _mmdButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = _mmdTextBox.Text;
    if (value > 1999 && value < 0)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Value is to high");
    }
    else
    {
       // action
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get when I do it like the code above:

> Error  1   Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Comment: How can the value be greater than 1999 *and* less than 0? (Even when you've got the right type.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int value;
if(Int32.TryParse(_mmdTextBox.Text, out value)
{
    if (value > 1999)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Value is too high");
    }
    else if(value < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Value is too low");
    }
    else
    {
        // action
    }
}
else
{
    // not a number
}
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking for.  A separate message is needed for each case.

Comment: @Koornstra - no problem! Be very careful when parsing user input; you can never trust the user to get it right :)

Answer (score 1):

[`TextBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk.aspx) returns `string`. So your `value` will be *string*. You can't compare string with an integer using [`<`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z5wecxwa%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) or [`>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yxk8751b%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) operators.

From *MSDN*;

> **All numeric and enumeration types** define....

Try to convert your `value` to `int` if it is available.

```
int value;
if(Int32.TryParse(_mmdTextBox.Text, out value)
{
    if (value > 1999)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Value is too high");
    }
    if(value < 0)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Value is too low");
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvote wasnt from me but value can't be greater than 1999 and smaller than 0

Comment: `(value > 1999 && value < 0)` can never be true, you should address this in your answer

Comment: @DarrenDavies and DGibbs, Fool me :) Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement could be changed to look like this:

```
var value = Convert.ToInt32(_mmdTextBox.Text);  //Convert to int in order to compare against an int

if (value > 1999)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Value is to high");
}
else if (value < 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Value is to low");
}
else
{
    //Action
}
```

You are comparing the `value` as type `string` to type `int`.

`int.TryParse()` would be a better option for the `int` conversion as the user could enter anything.  (Like in Erno De Weerd's answer)

Comment: Only just a bit difrent

Answer (score 0):

C# is an strongly typed language and if you want to compare 2 value . They should be the same type . So you need to be convert text box text to int also you need a validation to be insure that the value which coming from text bot is int ok

I thought this will help full for you

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing `_mmdTextBox.Text` which is `string` to constant of type `int`! It is impossible!
You should convert the former to `int`:

```
   int value;
   if(!int.TryParse(_mmdTextBox.Text, out value)) 
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Bad integer value in textbox");
       return;
   }
```

Comment: Somebody here is very interested to Downvote people without any special reason!!!

Answer (score -1):

How can something be > 1999 AND < 0 ?

TryParse might be better for your conversion but this should work:

```
private void _mmdButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var value = Convert.ToInt32(_mmdTextBox.Text);

            if (value > 1999)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value is too high");
            }
            else if (value < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value is too low");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value is ok");
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you copied my answer? hehe!

Comment: Nope - I think we wrote it at the same time - I was distracted by some work as I was writing the code so it took me a while to post. This happens a lot in SO :-) Also, how could I copy your code yet make it look different ?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem ist, that value is a string and not a number. You can use Parse or TryParse to solve it.

If you want to use `.TryParse()` make it look like [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/f02979c7.aspx) from MSDN:

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
if (result)
{
    if (number > 1999 || number < 0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Value is invalid");
    }
    else
    {
       // action
    }
}
else
{
   //Show that the input is not a numeric value
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it for instead of your if condition

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(value) > 1999 && !Convert.ToInt32(value)< 0)
```

Comment: That statement can never be true. How can `value` be greater than `1999` and less than `0`?

Comment: Sorry , Now am change my answer . Sorry

Comment: The condition still doesn't make sense.